# How a ClearCase trigger can be called to validate a file being checked in?

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I am new to ClearCase trigger. My requirements include the following point:

1. When user is trying to check in a file  using CCRC  I need to validate the code being checked in using a PMD tool.
   So I need to write a trigger which calls this PMD tool (accessble by CC server) and validate the code being checked in and if code is fine, then I can proceed. Otherwise it should throw error.
2. Also I need to know how triggers are installed.
3. Since CC server is not on my local and currently in use by other team mates, I think I need to get it on local to test this. Otherwise it will give issue to others if I test it directly there.

How would you address those points?

Answer (score 0):

A good source for "hooks" (called trggier) for CCRC is the IBM article "[Writing triggers for the ClearCase Remote Client](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21207634)" (for CCRC 7.x, which is different from ClearTeam explorer 8.x)

The main issue is that you cannot use clearprompt (which is a full clearcase command, not available with a CCRC client).
See [this script](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21640635) for an example on how to write a trigger which detects a CCRC environment.

```
$ppid=$ENV{"CLEARCASE_PPID"}; 
$taskline = `tasklist | findstr $ppid`; 
$taskname = substr ($taskline,0,index($taskline,"exe")+3); 
if ($taskname eq "clearexplorer.exe") 
{ 
...
}

else 
{ 
    print STDERR $outtext; 
}
```

Comment: 1) Now the issues is i have called PMD tool to validate my code. now i need to handle the response from PMD and based on that i need to display message to the user. like if the validation is success, success message and if filed failure. so can you helo me how can i handle that in perl scripts that is my trigger. 

2) what does these ENV variable mean and what do they return.
a)CLEARCASE_PN
b)CLEARCASE_VOB_PN

3)please clarify what happen if more than 1 person are trying to validate the file through trigger? will clear case will handle taht ??


please answer point wise. thanks in advance :)

Comment: @user3274878 1/ You will have to test it out, I never written that kind of trigger. 2/ `CLEARCASE_PN` is the path name of the file involved by the trigger. `CLEARCASE_VOB_PN` is the path of the vob of the file, as in `\myvob` 3/ There shouldn't be any issue (same than when several people check-in the same file at the same time): the first one will do so successfully, the other ones will have to merge that new version (done by the first) to their version before being finally able to check it in.

Comment: hi,
i have successfully acheived the above task CC_Trigger->batchfile->javaProgram. and also got the return object . now i wanted to stop the process if the status is failure and proceed with checkin if the status is success. how can i do taht please let me knw

Comment: @user3274878 I believe the simple fact that your trigger script returns a non-zero status is enough for the ClearCase operation to be stopped.

Comment: hi VONC,
thanks for the replies so far, now m at a place where i have processe everything but the display of message to user in case of failure is not working fine with me . i just have to display a message like "Validation Failed" with and "OK" button and then it shouldnt proceed with check in. but i am not able to acheive this. 

PFB my code:
if($output==0){
system("clearprompt  proceed -prompt \"Success in validation\"  -mask proceed -prefer_gui ");
exit 0;

}
else
{
system("clearprompt yes_no -prompt \"Validation Failed !! \" -default abort -mask abort -prefer_gui");
exit 1;
}

Comment: can u please repli ??

Comment: @user3274878 sorry, it is best to mark that question as resolve and ask a new one, with a reference back to this one.